# How to execute multiple other cases inside of a case

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, pattern-matching

So it is possible to fall-through the case to another case:

```js
switch(variable) {
  case 1:
    // do something 1
  case 2:
    // do something 2
    break;
  case 3:
    // do something 3
    break;
}
```

But what if we would want to execute multiple other cases after finishing the main case, or execute other case that is **not** directly after the main case?
Pseudocode for example:

```js
switch(variable) {
  case 1:
    // do something 1
    break;
  case 2:
    // do something 2
    break;
  case 3:
    // do something 3
    execute case 2;
    execute case 1;
    break;
}
```

I've researched the option of labeled statements, but it's not gonna work here it seems.
The only option I see here is to create new function for every case, but I'm wondering - is there better, cleaner, more readable and/or shorter option?

I'm looking for all tips - be it some keyword I'm missing, your personal tips to do it cleanly, or libraries and even propositions from other languages like typescript etc.

Comment: Maybe wrap the whole `switch` in a function that accepts `variable` and do a recursive call?

Comment: That pseudo-code of yours doesn't make alot of sense. What is supposed to happen if - via `execute case 2` - the `break` in case 2 is reached which _ends_ the switch-case statement? You could never end up executing case 1.

Comment: How about using named functions? ... like `doSomething_1`, `doSomething_2`, `doSomething_3` where the latter is implemented like this ... `function doSomething_3() { doSomething_2(); doSomething_1(); }`, and where one does invoke exactly one case specific function for each matching case.

Comment: just use `if..else if...else`, `switch` is less versatile

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Woa that is literally a meme making the rounds in dev circles. Don't (mecessarily) do that. It might be "less versatile" but it's a pretty dang good pattern if you are matching a single variable to multiple outcomes, like predefined constants.

Comment: @somethinghere if it's a single variable that mapping would be a good alternative. anyway i don't remember that i used `switch` in the recent years. there's always some limitations or better alternatives available

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I use switch all the time, with constants that get passed around to route things, to see if certain values match instead of making 10 "if" conditions. `switch` has its purposes, and if you _can_ use it, using a string of `if`/`else` is _not_ the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nick Parson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146502/js-execute-multiple-other-cases-inside-of-a-case#comment137769541_78146502) gave this awesome idea:

> Maybe wrap the whole switch in a function that accepts variable and do a recursive call?

Which works perfectly in this situation; So to incorporate it to example I posted and accept it as an answer:

```js
mySwitch(variable);
function mySwitch(_v) {
  switch(_v) {
    case 1:
      // do something 1
    break;
    case 2:
      // do something 2
    break;
    case 3:
      // do something 3
      mySwitch(2);
      mySwitch(1);
    break;
  }
}
```

It's clean, does the trick... and moreover - if you declare function where switch statement normally would be (in example inside some outer function), you will be able to change variables declared in the outer function, just like you would be able to inside switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> How about using **named functions**? ... like `doSomething_1`, `doSomething_2`, `doSomething_3` where the latter is implemented like this ... `function doSomething_3() { doSomething_2(); doSomething_1(); }`, and where one does **invoke exactly one case specific function for each matching case**.

Since the OP clearly is in control of the *switch-case* related code, why not implementing each case specific handling as own function. Thus, firstly decoupling the implementation of the case specific handling from the `mySwitch` function (the one of the OP's own answer) and secondly enabling code-reuse for the OP's example code's 3rd case.

The next provided example code in my eyes is much easier to comprehend than what the OP did come up with in his own answer ...

```js
function mySwitch(value) {
  switch (value) {
    case 1:
      handleCase1();
      break;
    case 2:
      handleCase2();
      break;
    case 3:
      handleCase3();
      break;
  }
}
console.log('mySwitch(1) ...');
mySwitch(1);

console.log('mySwitch(2) ...');
mySwitch(2);

console.log('mySwitch(3) ...');
mySwitch(3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
function handleCase1() {
  console.log('handling case 1');
}
function handleCase2() {
  console.log('handling case 2');
}
function handleCase3() {
  console.log('handling case 3 which invokes handling of 2 and 1');

  handleCase2();
  handleCase1();
}
</script>
```

... and in case the switch value is clearly either string or number based, one could shorten the above `mySwitch` function to ...

```js
function mySwitch(value) {
  ({
    '1': handleCase1,
    '2': handleCase2,
    '3': handleCase3,
  })[String(value)]?.();
}
console.log('mySwitch(0) ...');
mySwitch(0);

console.log('mySwitch(1) ...');
mySwitch(1);

console.log('mySwitch(2) ...');
mySwitch(2);

console.log('mySwitch(3) ...');
mySwitch(3);

console.log('mySwitch(4) ...');
mySwitch(4);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
function handleCase1() {
  console.log('handling case 1');
}
function handleCase2() {
  console.log('handling case 2');
}
function handleCase3() {
  console.log('handling case 3 which invokes handling of 2 and 1');

  handleCase2();
  handleCase1();
}
</script>
```